# Swift : pictures as Buttons

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm very new to App/Game design; I started with a basic app for my daughter.

How to create a small picture as a button in Xcode Swift?
If I click that picture, it should beep a sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the easier UI solution. Save the picture in images.xcassets folder in Xcode and make sure the size matches to the custom button size. Once you make the picture as background image, it becomes the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
let button = UIButton()
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "myImage.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("myFuncName"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: I found the easier UI solution. Save the picture in images.xcassets folder in Xcode and make sure the size matches to the custom button size. Once you make the picture as background image, it becomes the button.